# What is the lifespan of each data storage area in ASP .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've seen some explanations of these, but nothing that really compares where they start, end, or overlap, or good examples of their use.

What is the life span of each of the following data collections? And am I missing any?

- Application
- Session
- ViewData
- TempData

Answer (score 12, accepted):

application: as long as your application is running.  your application may be automatically shutdown and restarted by the server for various reasons

session: as long as the user is actively using your site.  this is generally determined by cookies that ASP.NET sends down to give each user a unique ID that expires after a while.  there are lots of ways to customize & tweak this to meet various needs

viewdata: as long as the current request is being processed.  this is used for sending data from a controller to a view for immediate rendering and thus not persisted

tempdata: until the value is read back out OR until the end of processing the *next* request in the session OR when the session ends/expires - whichever is sooner.  this is meant to be used for moving data from one controller to another when you are issuing a Redirect

Comment: Session lifespan is actually "as long as the user is actively using your site and the application is not restarted", at least if session data is stored in-process. This appears to be the standard configuration.

Comment: I would modify the definition for "application" to include, "or if the application pool is recycled".  This is important as the application pool might be recycled automatically based on resource utilization.  Because of this, if you have a bug in your code that introduces a memory leak, the app domain might get restarted and thus wipe out Application and Session storage (if the Session is stored InProc, as noted above)

Comment: Actually the lifespan of Tempdata does not end with the next request. I just tested it on an MVC4 application, and the tempdata was available until the value was read back.

Answer (score 2):

**Application :** This get initiated at the time when an application start and end when the application stops the execution.If user leaves the application domain or application gets restarted then also the application based data is lost.

**Session :** This is application based storage. This ends when user leaves the current request or the session get expired. It can be stored in several modes like application cookie or client side cookie.

**ViewBag & ViewData :** This storage method hold the data for the current request. It transport the data between view and controller.

**TempData :** Lifespan of this storage type depends on, at which request the Tempdata is read. Once it is read by program it gets destroyed. But we can increase its lifespan using `peek` or `keep` methods.