# Is there a way to pass value from one page to another in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any other way to pass value from one view to another or one controller to another apart from the methods below

- Viewdata
- TempData
- Viewbag

or passing inline in page redirect code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588420/what-is-the-lifespan-of-each-data-storage-area-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: you can always use `Session` object to store data along with the user session, but why would you like to do so? each View should have it's own data model with it's specific relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Any sort of communication between the views, excluding nested views i.e. partials, should go via the controller. That's kinda the whole point of MVC.

It sounds to me like you are sort of trying to get around the M/C part of the framework therefore it leads me to question is it the right tool for you to be using.

Comment: When you say "MVC part"  i think the key is the http application architecture is stateless and as such there are a number of documeneted workarounds and patterns in order to pass data between requests.

Comment: @SiRobinson I said "M/C part" as in the OP is looking to skip the model/controller and go straight for direct communication between the views - that pretty much makes an MVC architecture redundant here.